# postgres replica crashs after a successful failover

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, failover, crunchy-postgresql-operator

I have crunchy postgres operator running on a kubernetes cluster with 3 worker nodes deployed using kubespray (bare metal), I have setup one replica to switch on when the primary is down.
the state of the replica was running and synced with postgres master with no lag, for test reasons, I have stopped the node which the master postgres is running on it, the failover to the replica was done, and postgres become availbale after a moment.

When I restart up the stopped node, the postgres instance on it become crashed and the lag details become unknown:

```
Every 2.0s: patronictl list                                                                                                                                                        
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
| Member                    | Host                                    | Role    | State   | TL | Lag in MB |
+ Cluster: pg-metal-ha (7075323376834977860) -------------------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
| pg-metal-instance1-hfdp-0 | pg-metal-instance1-hfdp-0.pg-metal-pods | Replica | running |    |   unknown |
| pg-metal-instance1-zdc6-0 | pg-metal-instance1-zdc6-0.pg-metal-pods | Leader  | running |  2 |           |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
```

the log of the crashed instance pod is:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  index "pg_database_oid_index" contains unexpected zero page at block 0
HINT:  Please REINDEX it.
```

The hint didn't worked, I can't reindex the index "pg_database_oid_index" using psql, and this is th output of `psql` command:

```
bash-4.4$ psql
psql: error: FATAL:  index "pg_database_oid_index" contains unexpected zero page at block 0
HINT:  Please REINDEX it.
```

I redo the failover test many times with newly created postgres clusters, and I got the same result. is this a bug in crunchy-postgres-operator?

#### k8s version:

```
# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.5", GitCommit:"aea7bbadd2fc0cd689de94a54e5b7b758869d691", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T21:10:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.5", GitCommit:"aea7bbadd2fc0cd689de94a54e5b7b758869d691", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T21:04:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

#### postgres.yaml :

```
apiVersion: postgres-operator.crunchydata.com/v1beta1
kind: PostgresCluster
metadata:
  name: pg-metal
  namespace: prj-metal

spec:
  image: registry.developers.crunchydata.com/crunchydata/crunchy-postgres-gis:centos8-13.6-3.0-0
  postgresVersion: 13
  users:
    - name: pg
      options: "SUPERUSER"
  instances:
    - name: instance1
      replicas: 2
      dataVolumeClaimSpec:
        storageClassName: "ins-ls"
        accessModes:
        - "ReadWriteOnce"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 75Gi
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            labelSelector:
              matchLabels:
                postgres-operator.crunchydata.com/cluster: pg-metal
                postgres-operator.crunchydata.com/instance-set: instance1
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster (your config file)? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem. If your postgres was damaged you can [started with the -P option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-reindex.html).

Comment: I have updated the question, I will  try the -P option, but I'm  looking for the cause of the crash, because it is repeated in all tests I did.